# How to isolate traffic between VMs within openvswitch?

Tags: openvswitch

I've trying to achieve traffic isolation between VMs inside openvswitch with using VLANs.

But I've faced with issue that when I've set VLAN tag on VM's port VM can't access external physical network.

I think it's happens because my external physical network has no VLANs support or openvswitch doesn't allows untagget inbound traffic.

I've tried to use `strip_vlan` action to drop all VLANs for outgoing/incoming traffic but without success.

So my question is: How to isolate traffic between VMs with openvswitch only in network which doesn't support VLANs or VLAN tags are unknown?